# Replace entry in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

maybe this this question has been answered but I can't find any help on the web.

Here is my base JSON file :

```
[{"ID":"4215","date":"2017-05-24T05:41:44","text_wall":"Petite photo de Valence prise dimanche ","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0056.jpeg","ville_wall":"Valence "},

{"ID":"4147","date":"2017-05-18T15:15:02","text_wall":"#lyon #paris #valence Flixbus !","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0031.jpg","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand"},

{"ID":"3834","date":"2017-05-16T03:54:27","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/SAM_7590.jpg","text_wall":"Nouvelle station de travail Dell E4300"},]
```

Here I'd like the change the "date", "text_wall" and "ville_wall" from PHP.

Here is my PHP code as far as my knowledge goes and it's not working :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

$id    = $_POST['id'];
$text  = $_POST['text_wall'];
$ville = $_POST['ville_wall'];
$date  = date("c");

$jsonString = file_get_contents('text.json');
$list = json_decode($jsonString);

//Here is the problem I think
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {

  if ($list[$i]->ID === $id) {
$list[$i]['text_wall'] = $text;
  }
}

$list = array_values($list);

$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($list));
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: first of all you need to remove the , before the closing ] to make this valid JSON

Comment: Yes of course I forgot to remove it when I posted it. I had to shorten to 3 entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this perhaps - assigning the values to replace into an array and iterate through.

```
$id=!empty( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : 4147;

$text=!empty( $_POST['text_wall'] ) ? $_POST['text_wall'] : 'Humboldt Squid are vicious mofos';
$ville=!empty( $_POST['ville_wall'] ) ? $_POST['ville_wall'] : 'Bananas are generally yellow';
$date=date('c');


$replace=array( /* Replace these keys with these values */
    'date'          =>  $date,
    'text_wall'     =>  $text,
    'ville_wall'    =>  $ville
);


$keys=array_keys( $replace );

/* Contents from text file ~ trailing comma removed!!! */
$strjson='[
            {"ID":"4215","date":"2017-05-24T05:41:44","text_wall":"Petite photo de Valence prise dimanche ","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0056.jpeg","ville_wall":"Valence "},
            {"ID":"4147","date":"2017-05-18T15:15:02","text_wall":"#lyon #paris #valence Flixbus !","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0031.jpg","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand"},
            {"ID":"3834","date":"2017-05-16T03:54:27","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/SAM_7590.jpg","text_wall":"Nouvelle station de travail Dell E4300"}
        ]';
/* decoded file contents */
$json=json_decode( $strjson );


/* iterate over json object */
foreach( $json as $i => $obj ){
    /* Only replace for specified ID */
    if( $obj->ID==$id ){
        /* iterate through replacements */
        foreach( $replace as $key => $value ){
            $obj->$key=$value;
        }
    }
}
/* for testing */
echo '<pre>',print_r($json,true),'</pre>';

/* Convert back to json string */
$json=json_encode($json);

/* Save the file */
$bytes=file_put_contents('text.json',$json);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Your json is invalid. Need to remove last `,`from jsonstring. Then try following code.

```
$jsonString = '[{"ID":"4215","date":"2017-05-24T05:41:44","text_wall":"Petite photo de Valence prise dimanche ","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0056.jpeg","ville_wall":"Valence "},

{"ID":"4147","date":"2017-05-18T15:15:02","text_wall":"#lyon #paris #valence Flixbus !","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/IMG_0031.jpg","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand"},

{"ID":"3834","date":"2017-05-16T03:54:27","ville_wall":"Clermont-Ferrand","image_wall":"https:\/\/www.originsphotography.eu\/model\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/05\/SAM_7590.jpg","text_wall":"Nouvelle station de travail Dell E4300"}]';



$list = json_decode($jsonString);


foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
  if ($value->ID == $id) {
    $value->text_wall = $text;
  }
}
$list = array_values($list);
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($list));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: try edited answer change condition to `if ($value->ID == $id) {` remove extra `=` to ignore type